# Javascript - Scroll to bottom on a pop-up window

Tags: javascript, html, popup

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// Popup window code
function newPopup(url) {
    popupWindow = window.open(url,'popUpWindow','height=500, width=800, left=10, top=10, resizable=yes, scrollbars=yes, toolbar=yes, menubar=no, location=no, directories=no, status=yes')
}
</script>


<a href="JavaScript:newPopup('http://www.google.ca');">CLICK HERE</a></a> to go to google.
```

When the user click on `CLICK HERE` on the webpage, a pop-up window will appear and it directs you to the `http://www.google.ca` web page. My question is how do I make it so that the pop-up window will automatically scroll to the bottom on the page when `CLICK HERE` is clicked?

I found this code segment:
`window.scrollBy(0,50)`, but it scrolls the website itself to the bottom. It doesn't scroll the popup window.

Answer (score 1):

Try use `onload` event like this

```
function newPopup(url) {
    popupWindow = window.open(url,'popUpWindow','height=500, width=800, left=10, top=10, resizable=yes, scrollbars=yes, toolbar=yes, menubar=no, location=no, directories=no, status=yes');
    popupWindow.onload = function () {
        popupWindow.scrollTo(0, popupWindow.document.body.scrollHeight);
    };
}
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to be scrolling to the bottom of the pop-up. I'm using Google Chrome.

Comment: Domain name in the main window and the secondary window must be same. It is because of the cross-domain script security restriction (also referred as the "Same Origin Policy").

Comment: I used your code, but it didn't do anything to my pop-up.

Comment: Yeah! It works :) SOP will block if its different domain!

Answer (score 0):

You could try creating an anchor?

```
<a name="whereYouWantToScrollTo">Click To Scroll To Top</A>
```

http://www.webmastercourse.com/articles/anchors/
I'm not sure if you can activate an anchor with JavaScript, but that's the only way I know how to force the user to scroll down on a webpage.  Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

if your popup has an id you can use this code to get at the top of that popUp.

```
$("#confirma_modificacion_documento").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "fast");
```

when your popUp is:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="confirma_modificacion_documento" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true"
```